# example of a continuous function that is closed but not open

Tags: general-topology

Give an example of a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that is closed but not open.

$ f(x)=x^2$ is continuous and not open but It's not closed. What is an example?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the simplest functions you can think of?

Comment: Do you have an example showing that the mentioned function is not closed?

Comment: Hint : You need to find a function $f$ such that the image of ANY set will be closed. Maybe you can think of it this way. Any subset of $Im(f)$ will be closed, this means, by definition that $Im(f)$ is discrete.

Comment: @Daniel: Now that’s what I call getting right to the point! `:-)`

Comment: Thank for your hints, now I understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As several people have noted, there are much simpler examples, but in fact the squaring map $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto x^2$ *is* closed.

Let $F$ be a closed set in $\Bbb R$. Let $F_0=F\cap[0,\to)$; $F_0$ is closed in $[0,\to)$, and $f\upharpoonright[0,\to)$ is a homeomorphism of $[0,\to)$ onto itself, so $f[F_0]$ is a closed set in $[0,\to)$ and hence in $\Bbb R$. Similarly, if $F_1=F\cap(\leftarrow,0]$, then $f[F_1]$ is closed in $\Bbb R$, because $f\upharpoonright(\leftarrow,0]$ is a homeomorphism of $(\leftarrow,0]$ onto $[0,\to)$. But then $f[F]=f[F_0]\cup f[F_1]$ is closed in $\Bbb R$, and hence $f$ is a closed map.

(In case some of the notation is unfamiliar, $[0,\to)$ is another notation for $[0,\infty)$, and $f\upharpoonright A$ is the restriction of the function $f$ to the set $A$, also sometimes written $f|A$ or $f|_A$.)

Comment: It looks like the crucial step in your proof is that $f|_{\mathbb R^+}$ is a homeomorphism. Please prove this.

Comment: @pre-kidney: It’s trivial, since the map in question is continuous, monotone, and surjective.

Comment: This result might not be so trivial for the OP, given that it is more difficult to solve than the current question!  :P

Comment: @pre-kidney: True, but I posted it as a secondary answer, merely to point out the misconception and sketch an explanation; if the OP wants more detail, I can always add it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - I've been trying to think of an example of a map that satisfies being continuous, closed but also onto: would the map $x \to cos(x)$ defined on $[0,2\pi]$ onto $[-1,1]$ work? I feel like this is true but can't seem to find an open set thats **not** mapped to an open set.

Comment: @TaylorRendon: No, it’s open as well as closed. But if you map $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ to $\langle 1,\theta\rangle$ (polar coordinates) on the unit circle, you get a continuous, closed surjection that is not open: $[0,1)$ is open in the domain, but its image is not an open set on the circle.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So the map you are talking about is not the $cos(x)$ map that I mentioned? The one you mentioned is $\theta \to \langle 1,\theta \rangle$ from $[0,2\pi]$ to the unit circle (which gives a continuous, closed surjection that is not open)?

Comment: @TaylorRendon: Yes, that’s right.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the constant function $f(x)\equiv 0$, which is clearly continuous. Then for any set $E\subset \mathbb R$, either $f(E)=\varnothing$ or $f(E)=\{0\}$, each of which is a closed set. Hence $f$ is closed.

To show that $f$ is not open, just observe that $\mathbb R$ is open but $f(\mathbb R)=\{0\}$ is not open.