# Closed function and the interior

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I have some troubles with the next problem:

> Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a closed function. Prove that for all $y\in Y$ and for all $U\subseteq X$ open set such that $f^{-1}[\{y\}]\subseteq U$ holds that $y\in\text{int}_{Y}\left(f[\text{cl}_X(U)]\right)$ where $\text{int}$ denotes the interior of a set and $\text{cl}$ denotes the closure of a set.

My attempt:

Let $y\in Y$ and $U\subseteq X$ an open set. Then

$f^{-1}[\{y\}]\subseteq U\subseteq\text{cl}_{X}(U)$. In this way, $f^{-1}[\{y\}]\subseteq \text{cl}_{X}(U)$. Then, $\{y\}\subseteq f[\text{cl}_{X}(U)]$, furthermore, $y\in\{y\}\subseteq f[\text{cl}_{X}(U)]$. Then, $y\in f[\text{cl}_{X}(U)]$ and like $f$ is closed, $f[\text{cl}_{X}(U)]$ is closed, but from here, I don't know how to continue my proof.

Another idea is take $X\setminus U$ (is closed because $U$ is open), then, like $f$ is closed, $f[X\setminus U]$ is closed. Furthermore, like $f^{-1}[\{y\}]\subseteq U$ then $f^{-1}[\{y\}]\not\subseteq X\setminus U$ and so, $y\notin X\setminus U$. Then, $y\in U$, but, from here, again, I don't know what can I do.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the result you are after is not true in general.

Consider the map $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where $f(x)=0\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, equip $\mathbb{R}$  with the standard topology.

As shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334211/example-of-a-continuous-function-that-is-closed-but-not-open), the zero function on $\mathbb{R}$ is a closed map.

Take the open set $(0,1)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. It is clear that $\emptyset=f^{-1}(\{1\})\subseteq (0,1)$, but $1\not\in$**int**$f($**cl**$(0,1))=$**int**$\{0\}=\emptyset$ as the only open set contained in the singleton is the empty set.

In order for your required result to be true, we additionally need to know that the map $f$ is a bijection. Then it follows as seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_and_closed_maps) that $f$ will be a homeomorphism, then it is also necessarily an open map.